# Amazon S3 - Anonymous TVM vs Identity TVM

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a social app similar to a facebook app.  Users upload photos and videos to the server.  I'm thinking about using Amazon S3 to store this user generated content.

Each of these photos / videos would be stored with the some sort of unique name / id associated with the user.

However, I'm wondering is the Anonymous TVM strategy adequate or do I have to implement some sort of strategy using Identity TVM's?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These two articles do a pretty good job describing the TVM and when to use the anonymous vs. the identity TVM:

- http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/Android/4611615499399490
- http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367